# Sorting scandir by size

Tags: php, html

I am not even sure if it's possible because i've looked at probs over 15 stackoverflow posts about sorting by size, but all of the solutions don't seem to work for my specific need.

My code:

```
<div class="container">
<?php
$viddir = $_GET['vid'];
$perpage = 10;
$page = (int)$_GET['page'];
if(!($page>0)) $page = 1;
$offset = ($page-1)*$perpage;
$video_dir = "$viddir/Videos/";
$videos = scandir($video_dir);
arsort($videos);
$ignore = array(".", "..", "index.php");
$total_files = sizeof($videos);
$total_pages = ceil($total_files/$perpage);

$videos1 = array_slice($videos, $offset, $perpage);
    foreach($videos1 as $curvid){
        if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
            echo "<a href=\"$video_dir$curvid\"><video controls loop><source src=\"". $video_dir . '/' . $curvid ."\"></video></a>\n" ;
        }
    } ?>
    </div>
```

And i wanna sort it by size/length of the video, is this even possible without breaking my code? I've tried a few glob solutions but none of them work for what i need.

If anyone can see some other solution to this, it would mean alot and would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: are you wanting to sort by running time or physical size? as if it's running time, you may be in for a bad time as bigger running time does not always equal bigger file size.

Comment: @Joshua Physical Size

Answer (score 0):

Do an initial loop of your `$videos` and build a new array that contains the video path `$video_dir$curvid` and get the file size of that file using the PHP function `filesize( filename )`.

```
$videoList = [];
foreach( $videos1 as $curvid ) {
  $videoList[] = array( 'filepath' => $video_dir$curid, 'filesize' => filesize( $video_dir$curid ) );
}

usort($videoList, function ($item1, $item2) {
  return $item1['filesize'] <=> $item2['filesize'];
});

foreach( $videoList as $video ) {
  // Build your html using $video['filepath']
}
```

Above code is from my head and isn't tested some changes may be needed, but should help to get you in the right direction.

Sorting by video length is a bit more involved you will probably require use of a library.

Comment: Hm, seems like it didnt sort by file size? I am getting shortest videos to longest videos seems like? I want biggest files to be first not from smallest to biggest

Comment: Ok what i did was revert change return $item1['filesize'] <=> $item2['filesize']; to return $item2['filesize'] <=> $item1['filesize']; and now it works, anyways can you recommend a library for sorting by video length?